# Can I wait for a loop of asynchronous operations to finish inside a synchronous function using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, foreach

I have a foreach loop which executes a number of asynchronous functions which receive data and render a table. 
I would like to call a second function after all of the async. calls in foreach loop were finished and the table is rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. 
Make each action that you call a Promise. 
Keep all of these promises as an array, then invoke [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
const promises:Promise<{}>[] = [];
myWhatever.forEach(
    item => {
         const promise = new Promise<{}>(
             (resolve, reject) => {
                 // Do something which ends up with resolve getting called
                 // at some point
             }
         );
         promises.push(promise);
    }
);
Promise.all(promises)
   .then(
      () => {
          // Perform your post render tasks here
      }
    );
```

You can simplify this further with by replacing `forEach` with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
const promises = myWhatever.map(
    item =>
        new Promise<{}>(
             (resolve, reject) => {
                 // Do something which ends up with resolve getting called
                 // at some point
             }
        )
);
Promise.all(promises)
   .then(
      () => {
          // Perform your post render tasks here
      }
    );
```

Comment: That's not actually finishing inside of a sync function, though.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise it had to be. I'll change it.

Comment: For the record, it's not actually possible. Once you start using async stuff, it's _always_ async. Of course you could ignore the Promise, but it's still there in the background. You can make it look like it's sync, but the function has to return a Promise.

Comment: @jhpratt I've removed the `await` call now.